# Azure Windows Virtual Machine with Different Language Version

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, installation, azure, language

I am trying to figure out how to create a new VM in Azure using and Italian version of Windows. I was successfully able to create an English VM and install the Italian language pack as this question suggests, but that is not the same as installing an actual Italian version of Windows. I haven't found any documentation of this from Azure other than a feature request that is several years old. Has anyone had any success getting a foreign language virtual machine in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that installing a native version of a foreign language OS is actually the same as installing an English version and adding the foreign language pack.  That means I was actually able to create an Italian Windows VM in Azure by using the Windows OS from the gallery and installing the Italian Language Pack.  I just needed to make sure that I applied the language pack to system-wide settings and not just the display language for the current user.